# CakePHP 3 Contains will give a multidimensional array

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have created a query function to select some periods and of each period the max date and the number of days.

```
$periods = $this->Periods->find('all')->contain([
    'Days' => function($q) {
        return $q->select([
            'Days.period_id',
            'max_date' => $q->func()->max('Days.date'),
            'count_days' => $q->func()->count('Days.period_id')
        ])->group(['Days.period_id']);
    }
]);
```

When I debug Days it will this:

```
 [
    (int) 0 => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {
        'period_id' => (int) 1,
        'max_date' => '2016-11-21',
        'count_days' => (int) 2,
        '[new]' => false,
        '[accessible]' => [
            '*' => true
        ],
        '[dirty]' => [],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[invalid]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'Periods.Days'
    }
    ]
```

Now my problem is that when I will use Days, I alway must use a number like `$period['days'][0]['max_date']` because it is a multidimensional array. How can I make that I can use `$period['days'][max_date]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your records are coming in correct format, as you are retrieving all the records.
Don't you need multiple records in that array ? If so you can retrieve only single row. Otherwise you can use foreach loop:

```
foreach($periods as $p) {
   echo $p->max_date;
   echo $p->count_days;
}
```